# What is the default password for the Remmina VNC server?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, vncserver

I am attempting to remote in to my sister's netbook using Remmina remote desktop client on both linux mint pc.  I get prompted for a VNC password, but I do not know what it is, or where were I could change it.

If you guys havy any idea what the default password is or how I could change the password, please let me know, I will really appreciate it.

ALSO-if you recommend any other Remote desktops tools for 2 linux mint pcs, please let me know.

UPDATE 09/18 10:25 EST-clients web site doesn't provide this information.

Comment: Personally, I use x11vnc, which prompts for passwords when you start the server (ie there is no "default"). Also, their [project page](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) says that Remmina is "a remote desktop **client**"; you need to find out what your actual server is.

Comment: @new123456 I will try x11vnc server. Remmina comes with a VNC plugin installed to manage VNC inbound/outbound connections named LibVNCServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password is the same used to login sister's desktop.

Configuration for the same can be done as follows:

Go to **Preferences > Remote Desktop** and select the following preferences:

1. Check "Allow other users to view your desktop";
2. Check "Allow other users to control your desktop";
3. Check the security settings you desire;

Now the password used to login to your sister's desktop will allow you to view the desktop. You may use a separate account if you desire.

Well the tool you are currently using uses VNC protocol which is quite fine.